# Kakashi's Mangekyou Sharingan

Tags: naruto

Obito starts using his Mangekyou as soon as he unlocks it,unlike Kakashi.

Did Kakashi not know he had the Mangekyou?Or did he keep it hidden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to clarify, the Mangekyo sharingan unlocked when Rin died. Thus, Kakashi *does* know that he has the ability to use Mangekyo sharingan the whole time through the series. Thus, he does know he has the Mangekyo.

Regarding whether he kept it hidden or not is up to the viewer's discretion. There's another thread that was open a few years ago on [When did Kakashi first use his Mangekyo sharingan](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/when-does-kakashi-first-use-his-mangekyou-sharingan), an excellent thread to see what other people think.

Personally, I'd say he tried to keep it hidden since he still couldn't properly wield it properly, and would be in danger